# MOC3043 possible failure

Tags: datasheet, opto-isolator, triac

Problem : BTA16 triac is always on with using MOC3043 as driver

Facts: BTA16 working correct when moc3043 is disconnected from it's gate pin.

Atmega8 output pin is connected to 330ohm resistor and it's output is working correct.

MOC3043 output is always on regardless of it's input state.

Question: According to MOC3043 datasheet, the maximum input current is 5 mA, is it possible that 330 ohm resistor with 5 volt cause MOC3043 input LED to burn out and it's output becoming always on?

[image]

Comment: Seems possible that it could have happened, or inductive spike on AC side somehow damaged MOC3043.

Comment: It's probably the opto-triac output that is fried.  You should be able to think of a way to test it out of circuit.  Your scheme for using it to drive the power triac may need more refinement.

Answer (score 1):

For 5mA, the MOC.. datasheet says you have < 1.2 V forward voltage.

That means (5-1.2) V = 3.8 V need to drop over R2.

3.8 V / 300 Ω = 13 mA

So, yeah, you're pushing about three times as much current through your LED as you should.

Comment: R = 330 Ohms, so I = 11.5 mA, but yeah -- over 2x maximum LED current.

Comment: Exactly, I'm considering overcurrent cause MOC3034 become faulty. however can't be sure that it was not faulty from seller.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

Problem was purely caused by faulty MOC3043.

I replace it with MOC3041M and every thing works as expected.

And also i don't know that MOC3043 was faulty from seller or somehow my circuit burn it out.